# sqlite3 objective c xcode

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

i am asked to develope a contactlist in objective c using sqlite where i am required to edit the data as well i have one viewcontroller and i pass data to the other viewcontroller which is a table view controller. i have no idea where to begin and what to do . any one who can share any links. as i am a learner and i want to begin from scratch. so as i understand it also.where should i start and what should i do?
i have not tried anything as yet i have just searched but not found any links.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have asked a very broad question. However here are some useful tutorials on all topics you have mentioned. Anyways I would recommend going through a complete set of tutorials to develop complete understanding and an ability to create custom applications not seeking for a tutorial every time you stumble upon a new task.

So, the links:

- First, passing data between view controllers. Using the delegate pattern is the best practice for this case: [link](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/)
- So for your contact app you might need two custom Table view controllers. So here's one for learning Table view controllers. [This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_tableview.htm) is a bit old but includes all neccessary information about displaying content and handling user interactions.
- Storage using SQLite3 is not he best practice for iOS development but here's an extremely [through tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/).
- I would recommend using Core Data in your further projects as it's the native way for storing data. [Another good tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/)